# Viewing the result of Facebook FQL query in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-fql

What is the best way to quickly view what is returned in result from a Facebook FQL query. Facebook sample code uses the following in request:didLoad

```
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

This I believe takes the "result" (originally NSArray) and makes it into an NSDictionary. Will the NSLog statement print the entire contents of the "result" (NSDictionary)?

Comment: What language are you working in? Add this to your question and your tags.

Comment: Objective-C. I updated the title and tags.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to quickly view what is returned in result from a Facebook FQL query.

If you’re just asking for debugging purposes (not entirely clear to me from your question) – the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) now has a tab for running FQL queries, too …

Comment: I mean, how to view it programatically (using Objective-C).

Comment: Printing "result" using NSlog is a quick way to view the data (for debugging purposes) obtained from a FQL multi-query. For detailed look into each query output, you can save each query's output into an NSDictionary, such as (3rd query result): NSDictionary *resultQuery2 = [result objectAtIndex:2] and then saving that result in an array, as: NSArray *resultQueryArray2 = [resultQuery2 objectForKey:@"fql_result_set"]. Now the array elements can be accessed, as (ith element in array, for album ID): NSString *myalbumID = [resultQueryArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"aid"]